# Dynamic D3 force graph

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I am trying to dynamically create a graph from a JSON file of the form:

```
{"nodes": [{"category": "...", "group": 1, "uid": 0, "number": 1, "complaints": [" ...,..."], "name": "..."}], "links": ['source':"",'target':"",'value':""]}
```

I can correctly draw the graph as I wish it to be displayed however when adding new nodes, the edges are not correctly formed and neither are the radius of the nodes (they are altered according to the number element in the JSON) I was not able to find any code to nor tutorials documenting how to do this in d3. However when you refresh the page the graph appears as I wish it to.

This is the code I have came up with so far in order to try doing so. I feel like there is just a minor change that needs to be made in order to make it work but I cant figure out what it is. The fact that it displays as I wish it to when I refresh the page tells me that there is something wrong with the restart function.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .node {
                stroke: #fff;
                stroke-width: 1.5px;
            }
            .link {
                stroke: #999;
                stroke-opacity: .6;
            }
            d3-tip {
                line-height: 1;
                color: black;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src="http://labratrevenge.com/d3-tip/javascripts/d3.tip.v0.6.3.js"> </script>
    </head>

    <b>
    </b>



    <script>

        $.ajaxSetup({cache: false});
        var json;
        getJSON();
        function getJSON(){
                $.ajax({
                    'async': false,
                    'global': false,
                    'url': "/categories.json",
                    'dataType': "json",
                    'success': function (data) {
                        json = data;
                        console.log("Updating JSON")
                    }
                });
                return json;
        }

        window.setInterval(function(){
            getJSON();
            restart();
        }, 5000);


        var width = 500,
            height = 500;

        var color = d3.scale.category20();

        var force = d3.layout.force()
            .charge(-120)
            .linkDistance(30)
            .size([width, height]);

        var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height);

        var tip = d3.tip()
            .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
            .offset([-10, 0])
            .html(function (d) {
            return  d.name + "</span>";
        })
        svg.call(tip);

        force.nodes(json.nodes)
            .links(json.links)
            .start();

        var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
            .data(json.links)
            .enter().append("line")
            .attr("class", "link")
            .style("stroke-width", function (d) {
            return Math.sqrt(d.value);
        });

        var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
            .data(json.nodes)
            .enter().append("circle")
            .attr("class", "node")
            .attr("r", function(d) {
                if(d.number >= 20){
                    return 50;
                }
                if(d.number > 1){
                    return ((d.number*1.3)+10);
                }else{
                    return d.number+4
                }

            })
            .style("fill", function (d) {
            return color(d.group);
        })
        .call(force.drag)
        .on('mouseover', tip.show)
        .on('mouseout', tip.hide);

        force.on("tick", function () {
            link.attr("x1", function (d) {
                return d.source.x;
            })
                .attr("y1", function (d) {
                return d.source.y;
            })
                .attr("x2", function (d) {
                return d.target.x;
            })
                .attr("y2", function (d) {
                return d.target.y;
            });

            node.attr("cx", function (d) {
                return d.x;
            })
                .attr("cy", function (d) {
                return d.y;
            });
        });

        function restart() {

          force = d3.layout.force()
            .charge(-120)
            .linkDistance(30)
            .size([width, height]);

          tip = d3.tip()
            .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
            .offset([-10, 0])
            .html(function (d) {
            return  d.name + "</span>";
          })
          svg.call(tip);

          link = svg.selectAll(".link")
            .data(json.links)
            .enter().append("line")
            .attr("class", "link")
            .style("stroke-width", function (d) {
            return Math.sqrt(d.value);
          });;

          // Apply the general update pattern to the nodes.
          node = svg.selectAll(".node")
            .data(json.nodes)
            .enter().append("circle")
            .attr("class", "node")
            .attr("r", function(d) {
                if(d.number >= 20){
                    return 50;
                }
                if(d.number > 1){
                    return ((d.number*1.3)+10);
                }else{
                    return d.number+4
                }

            })
            .style("fill", function (d) {
            return color(d.group);
          })
          .call(force.drag)
          .on('mouseover', tip.show)
          .on('mouseout', tip.hide);

          force.nodes(json.nodes)
            .links(json.links)
            .start();

          force.on("tick", function () {
            link.attr("x1", function (d) {
                return d.source.x;
            })
                .attr("y1", function (d) {
                return d.source.y;
            })
                .attr("x2", function (d) {
                return d.target.x;
            })
                .attr("y2", function (d) {
                return d.target.y;
            });

            node.attr("cx", function (d) {
                return d.x;
            })
            node.attr("cy", function (d) {
                return d.y;
            });
          });


        }
    </script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [minimal working example on plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/DhcbuHUegupxWpJGGHvX/) with 2 nodes and 1 link using your json format.

Im not entirely sure what your objective is with restart(), I assume you're loading the data from the file once? In any case, its not necessary to have the exact same logic on the force layout twice. You can have d3 add/update/remove logic in a function, then when data changes, call that function. The tick function only needs to be specified once also.

I commented out the tooltip code as I didnt want to debug that also, but I think the linked resource is not https! http://blockbuilder.org/search is a good resource for searching for d3 examples that may help to find good examples.

If you are happy with the answer, please mark it as an accepted answer and upvote.

Comment: My issue is I am trying to dynamically add new nodes to the graph, the reason for reloading the JSON file is because it continually changes as new elements are added to it. I am able to draw a graph however I can't add new nodes properly.

Comment: In your code, you are only handling new data via enter(). You need to deal with an update and a remove to handle a refreshed dataset properly. d3 compares the dom elements to the dataset to determine if it is an add/update/remove. you are not doing this. See this article for a good explaination https://medium.com/@c_behrens/enter-update-exit-6cafc6014c36